# Error: Type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated' is not defined

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

1- I have created WPF application  as you can see following picture.

2- I have visited following site.

3- I have copied XAML code as you can see following picture.

4- I have pasted the XAML code into my WPF application  as you can see following picture.

5- I have runned my WPF application and following error occurs. Do you have any idea how to solve following error?

Comment: Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices` in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you copied `<Page>` markup and replaced expected `<Window>` markup

copy inner content starting from Border and insert inside Window tag in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Border Width="400" BorderBrush="Black">
       <!--everything else-->
    </Border>

</Window>
```

(if MainWindow.xaml is lost just start over with a default wpf project template)